Rails: Proper convention for many one-to-one relationships in a single rails model
I have a "central" model that is referenced by many other models like this:
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :foo_a, foreign_key: :survey_a_id, inverse_of: :survey_a, class: 'Foo'
   has_one :foo_b, foreign_key: :survey_b_id, inverse_of: :survey_b, class: 'Foo'
   has_one :bar_a, foreign_key: :survey_a_id, inverse_of: :survey_a, class: 'Bar'
   has_one :bar_b, foreign_key: :survey_b_id, inverse_of: :survey_b, class: 'Bar'
end

With the Foo and Bar classes looking something like:
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey_a, class_name: 'Survey', inverse_of: :foo_a
  belongs_to :survey_b, class_name: 'Survey', inverse_of: :foo_b
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey_a, class_name: 'Survey', inverse_of: :bar_a
  belongs_to :survey_b, class_name: 'Survey', inverse_of: :bar_b
end

As can be seen, the Survey model may contain 1 or more foreign keys in another model. In my actual business case, we do have a Survey-esque model which is then used by a bunch of different models. Other models can have 1 or more surveys associated with them but they are named / specific surveys, it's not enough to just use a has_many. For example, Foo can only have one "Survey A" and only one "Survey B" and those surveys are used for specific business logic within the application.
My question is, is there a better way to set this up with Rails?
What gives me concern with my current setup in my real application is that I currently have 11 has_one definitions in the Car model and it will continue to grow. I feel like there's a better way to do this but I'm not finding any.

This is the proper convention.  So: a) You may want to revisit your design -- why does the Car class need so many has one relationships or b) if the design solves the problems it was intended to -- live with it.

Would you mind elaborating? What is a Foo and a Bar really? I cannot think of anything that each car has always exactly two things of each. And therefore, I have a hard time suggesting a different database schema or a different association structure.

+1 for providing more information about your data structure and what it is intended to represent.
What you've shared so far suggests an anti-pattern which we can totally fix! But, we don't know enough yet to suggest alternatives.
It'll likely be a HABTM association though. Or an ordered has_many association.

Thanks all. I added more details on it and used Survey as the central model instead. What I am trying to convery is that surveys are used a lot in my application, but in very specific ways by other models like Foo and Bar. Those models can't have a has_many to surveys because my applications needs to be able to identify Foo's survey A vs its survey B.
STI / inheritance on the survey model doesn't make too much sense in this case either IMO because the surveys themselves all behave identically.

As soon as I see enumerated attributes --  survey A, survey B -- it is a code smell.  I'd have a Survey with a survey_type attribute that identifies if it is a type A or type B, and just have a has_many. Then I'd look how you modeled foo and bar, because I bet the belongs_to is probably causing more problems than it is solving.

I definitely like the idea of adding a "type" attribute right on survey and then adding a polymorphic association to it that could point to Foo or Bar. That seems strong than having all these has_one relationships everywhere.

What you sacrifice with polymorphic associations is any guarentee of referential integrity. Its a dirty rotten hack that's sometimes useful but usually just as much of an anti-pattern.
